# How do I insert data into a mysql database using a for loop?

Tags: php, mysql

My code is:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
mysql_select_db("cars",$conec);
array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  echo "$array[i] <br>";
  }
?>
```

What I want to do is insert each car into a database and this is what I tried to do but I only get the id increasing becuase it is an auto-increment

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $res = mysql_query("insert into auto (car) values ($array[i])")
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about PHP basics.

Comment: oh yeah, that's not my actual code. but it's what I want to do. Don't worry about the minor errors

Comment: All you have are lots of minor errors. How are we supposed to know which ones you did on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning your code up:-

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
mysql_select_db("cars",$conec);
$array = array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO auto (car) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($array[$i])."')");
}
?>
```

Using foreach for the loop, which saves working out how many elements there are first:-

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
mysql_select_db("cars",$conec);
$array = array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
foreach($array as $array_item)
{
    $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO auto (car) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($array_item)."')");
}
?>
```

Or just building a single INSERT to put in all the rows at once.

```
<?php

include("connect.php");
mysql_select_db("cars",$conec);
$array = array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO auto (car) VALUES ('".implode("'),('", array_map ('mysql_real_escape_string', $array))."')");

?>
```

Note that you should really be using mysqli_* functions now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `$` before variable names. And when substituting an expression into a string, you have to put `{}` around it. And since the values are SQL strings, you need to put quotes around them in the query.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $res = mysql_query("insert into auto (car) values ('{$array[$i]}')")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $res = mysql_query("insert into auto values ("'.$array[i].'")") or die ('SQL ERROR !'.$res.'<br />'.mysql_error());
}
```